# SQL SUM ON DISTINCT CURRENCIES

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 SQL Tables

First is expenses Table

```
id  |  currency_id  |  amount  |  Date
1   |            1  |     500  |  02/02/2017
2   |            1  |     200  |  02/02/2017
3   |            2  |     600  |  03/02/2017
4   |            1  |     400  |  03/02/2017
```

Second is currencies table

```
id  |  name
1   |  USD
2   |  INR
```

I want query output as sum of amount and distinct by currency. For example

```
name  |  amount  | Date
USD   |     700  | 02/02/2017
INR   |     600  | 03/02/2017
USD   |     400  | 03/02/2017
```

I have explored a lot of queries from stackoverflow and sql documentation, but couldn't find any query that give me this result. I have applied multiple combinations of SUM, DISTINCT and GROUP BY, but they are not giving any results.

Comment: Please include your best query attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to apply `GROUP BY` Clause with aggregation `SUM()`

```
SELECT c.name, sum(e.amount) amount, e.Date 
FROM expenses e
INNER JOIN currencies c ON c.id = e.currency_id   
GROUP BY c.name, e.Date
```

Comment: Thanks for your response